# How can yield return statement return no elements?

Tags: c#, methods, iterator, enumerator, yield-return

I'm practicing deletion of nodes on a binary search tree, and I created a special type for null links (**NullNode**) using null pattern, so I can add some desirable behaviour to "null" types. Both **Node** type and **Nullnode** type share the same **INode** interface, which includes recursive methods.

The **INode** interface includes **IEnumerable** recursive methods por PreOrder, InOrder and PostOrder traversal, but I don't want NullNode to return any element (through yield return statements).

What can I do?

I know that I can use an impossible if-condition and then put there a yield return statement in the method, but I don't think this solution is good. There should be a better approach.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to use `yield`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the yield break statement:

```
private static IEnumerable<INode> YieldEmpty()
{
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used to believe the the **yield break** statement would stop the whole iterator, but now I understand it better.

Answer (score 3):

Had you tried returning something like this for no returning nothing (or an empty enumerator):

```
return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

Or maybe using `yield break;` can be an alternative for exit yields loops. Hope this could help you...

Comment: The correct syntax is `Enumerable<T>.Empty()`... An interface can not have a static method

Comment: Thanks also, but I'm not in my machine. LinkPad is great!

Answer (score 2):

```
private static IEnumerable<T> ReturnNoElements()
{
   return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: Since `IEnumerable<T>` is a interface, it cannot be **newed**